# Which word is better: "finances" or "economy"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

If you have a section in a document, where you describe matters to do with an organisation's finances – for instance which departments are on budget; what projects will get extra funding; which activities will be funded how, and so on – which would be the better heading: *Finances* or *Economy*? Or should it be something else entirely, such as *Financial matters*, *Economic aspects* or...?

I'd greatly appreciate any help I can get here :)

Answer (score 2):

*Finances* would be the better choice. *Economy* tends to refer more to the macro level---the economy of a country, for example.

(There are of course exceptions, as for example when you talk about the *fuel economy*, basically meaning *fuel efficiency*, of a car.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the difference! And you'd say "Finances" is better than, for instance, "Financial matters/aspects"? That is, does "Finances" work also in the wider context described in my question, where aspects other than mere figures are discussed?

Comment: Yes, I don't think you need any extra words, especially not vague words like 'matters'. But I'm sure different organisations would have different preferences. I cannot guarantee that 'finances' is the best option, only that it is better than 'economy'.

Comment: Thank you, legatrix! Thing is, I'm translating a document for my employer, so it's up to me to determine what is the most appropriate translation... that is, I can't ask the organisation in question which word they'd prefer. Anyway – I think I'll go with "Finances" then :)